ValueError Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 2: given 1
I'm writing for the titled error that I'm having trouble to fix.
I have a dataframe contains 10 columns of 1000 rows. The data looks like :
ID DATE COL3 COL4....
1 2024-01-01
1 2024-01-02
1 2024-01-03
1 2024-01-04
2 2024-01-02
3 2024-01-03
3 2024-01-04 

I also have a zip object that was constructed of the id and dates only, about only 20 rows in total.
So what I'm trying to achieve is to match the df[['id', 'date']]  with the zip object and it's where the errors occurred:
df = np.choose( (t_trans_df[["id", "date"]] in id_date_zip).all())
Can someone give me some advice please? Much appreciated in advance!

Did you find useful one of the answer or you found a better solution?

If convert zip object to DataFrame, you can use merge with DataFrame.equals for test if values exist in pairs:
print (t_trans_df)
   ID        DATE  COL3  COL4
0   1  2024-01-01   NaN   NaN
1   1  2024-01-02   NaN   NaN
2   1  2024-01-03   NaN   NaN
3   1  2024-01-04   NaN   NaN
4   2  2024-01-02   NaN   NaN
5   3  2024-01-03   NaN   NaN
6   3  2024-01-04   NaN   NaN

print (df1)
   ID        DATE
0   2  2024-01-02
1   3  2024-01-03
2   3  2024-01-04


test = df1.merge(t_trans_df[df1.columns]).equals(df1)
print (test)
True

If need output DataFrame:
out = t_trans_df.merge(df1)
print (out)
   ID        DATE  COL3  COL4
0   2  2024-01-02   NaN   NaN
1   3  2024-01-03   NaN   NaN
2   3  2024-01-04   NaN   NaN

Solution with zip object:
id_date_zip = zip([2,3,3], 
                  ["2024-01-02", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-04"])


mux1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(t_trans_df[["ID", "DATE"]])
mux2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(id_date_zip)

print (mux1)
MultiIndex([(1, '2024-01-01'),
            (1, '2024-01-02'),
            (1, '2024-01-03'),
            (1, '2024-01-04'),
            (2, '2024-01-02'),
            (3, '2024-01-03'),
            (3, '2024-01-04')],
           names=['ID', 'DATE'])

print (mux2)
MultiIndex([(2, '2024-01-02'),
            (3, '2024-01-03'),
            (3, '2024-01-04')],
           )

out = t_trans_df[mux1.isin(mux2)]
print (out)
   ID        DATE  COL3  COL4
4   2  2024-01-02   NaN   NaN
5   3  2024-01-03   NaN   NaN
6   3  2024-01-04   NaN   NaN


If your dataframe is t_trans_df and id_date is your zip transformed into a list, one way to filter the dataframe based on the values in your zip for the columns ["ID", "DATE"] is to use apply:
l1 =[1,2,3]
l2 = ["2024-01-04", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-33"]
id_date = list(zip(l1, l2))

mask = t_trans_df.apply(
    lambda row: 
        True if tuple(row[["ID", "DATE"]]) in id_date 
        else False, 
    axis=1)

display(t_trans_df.loc[mask]) gives:

